# don't know why, nginx proxy_pass not working

Tags: nginx

I config nginx prox_pass, but it does not work,
access / works fine, but get 404 when access /v2/
my config file is :

> server {
>
> ```
> listen 80;
>
> listen 443 ssl;
>
> server_name my.com;
>
> location / {
>
>     proxy_pass http://localhost:8443;
>
>     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
>
>     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
>
>     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
>
> }
>
> location /v2/ {
>
>     proxy_pass http://localhost:9443;
>
>     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
>
>     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
>
>     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
>
> }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Is you proxy at `http://localhost:9443` listening for /v2/ ?